# Apache Beam WriteToJdbc : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have apache beam pipeline to read data from a file, process it and ingest it to a RDBMS(MySQL in this case) with help of apache beam library WriteToJdbc.

Data is in ndjson format which is flattened and the lenght of each record may vary.

Pipeline:

```
import argparse
import json
import logging
from sys import argv

import apache_beam as beam
import flatsplode
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import WriteToJdbc
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

data_targets = {"rdbms": {
"rdbms properties"
}}


class ProcessData(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        element = json.loads(element)
        flat_json = flatsplode.flatsplode(element, "_")
        for data in flat_json:
            yield data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    read_data = p | "Read Text" >> beam.io.ReadFromText("data.json")

    process_data = read_data | "Process JSON" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessData())

    # process_data | beam.Map(print)

    process_data | f"Write to RDBMS" >> WriteToJdbc(
        table_name=data_targets["rdbms"]["tablename"],
        driver_class_name=data_targets["rdbms"]['driver_class_name'],
        jdbc_url=data_targets["rdbms"]['jdbc_url'],
        username=data_targets["rdbms"]['username'],
        password=data_targets["rdbms"]['password'])

    p.run()
```

I got this issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/cloud_repo/albertsons/python_ingestion/test.py", line 53, in <module>
    process_data | f"Write to RDBMS" >> WriteToJdbc(
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 137, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 655, in apply
    return self.apply(
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 666, in apply
    return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 712, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 142, in apply
    return super().apply(transform, input, options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 185, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 215, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 605, in expand
    raise RuntimeError(response.error)
RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1. Known URNs: [beam:coder:avro:generic:v1, beam:coder:bytes:v1, beam:coder:bool:v1, beam:coder:string_utf8:v1, beam:coder:kv:v1, beam:coder:varint:v1, beam:coder:interval_window:v1, beam:coder:iterable:v1, beam:coder:timer:v1, beam:coder:length_prefix:v1, beam:coder:global_window:v1, beam:coder:windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:param_windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:double:v1, beam:coder:row:v1, beam:coder:sharded_key:v1, beam:coder:custom_window:v1, beam:coder:nullable:v1]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents.getPCollection(RehydratedComponents.java:139)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.lambda$expand$0(ExpansionService.java:497)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:178)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet.lambda$entryConsumer$0(Collections.java:1576)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1601)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:492)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:606)
        at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:305)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:354)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1. Known URNs: [beam:coder:avro:generic:v1, beam:coder:bytes:v1, beam:coder:bool:v1, beam:coder:string_utf8:v1, beam:coder:kv:v1, beam:coder:varint:v1, beam:coder:interval_window:v1, beam:coder:iterable:v1, beam:coder:timer:v1, beam:coder:length_prefix:v1, beam:coder:global_window:v1, beam:coder:windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:param_windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:double:v1, beam:coder:row:v1, beam:coder:sharded_key:v1, beam:coder:custom_window:v1, beam:coder:nullable:v1]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents.getCoder(RehydratedComponents.java:168)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PCollectionTranslation.fromProto(PCollectionTranslation.java:51)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$3.load(RehydratedComponents.java:108)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$3.load(RehydratedComponents.java:98)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1. Known URNs: [beam:coder:avro:generic:v1, beam:coder:bytes:v1, beam:coder:bool:v1, beam:coder:string_utf8:v1, beam:coder:kv:v1, beam:coder:varint:v1, beam:coder:interval_window:v1, beam:coder:iterable:v1, beam:coder:timer:v1, beam:coder:length_prefix:v1, beam:coder:global_window:v1, beam:coder:windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:param_windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:double:v1, beam:coder:row:v1, beam:coder:sharded_key:v1, beam:coder:custom_window:v1, beam:coder:nullable:v1]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:440)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.fromKnownCoder(CoderTranslation.java:165)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.fromProto(CoderTranslation.java:145)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$2.load(RehydratedComponents.java:87)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$2.load(RehydratedComponents.java:82)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 38 more
```

I tried using

```
process_data | beam.Map(lambda x: x).with_output_types(typing.Iterable[str]) | f"Write to RDBMS" >> WriteToJdbc(
        table_name=data_targets["rdbms"]["tablename"],
        driver_class_name=data_targets["rdbms"]['driver_class_name'],
        jdbc_url=data_targets["rdbms"]['jdbc_url'],
        username=data_targets["rdbms"]['username'],
        password=data_targets["rdbms"]['password'])
```

but got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/cloud_repo/albertsons/python_ingestion/test.py", line 46, in <module>
    process_data | beam.Map(lambda x: x).with_output_types(typing.Iterable[str]) | f"Write to RDBMS" >> WriteToJdbc(
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 137, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 655, in apply
    return self.apply(
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 666, in apply
    return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 712, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 142, in apply
    return super().apply(transform, input, options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 185, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 215, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/home/somnath_c_datametica_com/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 605, in expand
    raise RuntimeError(response.error)
RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getSchema(PCollection.java:331)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcSchemaIOProvider$JdbcSchemaIO$2.expand(JdbcSchemaIOProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcSchemaIOProvider$JdbcSchemaIO$2.expand(JdbcSchemaIOProvider.java:140)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:548)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:499)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$TransformProvider.apply(ExpansionService.java:400)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:526)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:606)
        at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:305)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:354)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p48p1.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

To overcome this I used

```
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow', pcoll_schema)
coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)
```

but this didn't work either

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you see if this post helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71077551/unknown-coder-urn-beamcoderpickled-pythonv1-when-running-beam-with-a-custom-e

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html#apache_beam.io.jdbc.WriteToJdbc) of `WriteToJdbc` it requires the input rows in the form of a `NamedTuple` (see [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas-for-pl-types)):

> A PTransform which writes Rows to the specified database via JDBC.
> This transform receives **Rows defined** as **NamedTuple** type and **registered**
> in the **coders** registry

which need to be registered in the coder registration. If you allow me to steal the example from `WriteToJdbc` you need to write something like this

```
# define NamedTuple
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow',
                               [('id', int), ('name', unicode)])
# Register Coder
coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)

with TestPipeline() as p:
  _ = (
      p
      | beam.Create([ExampleRow(1, 'abc')])
          .with_output_types(ExampleRow)   # use name of registered coder as output type
      | 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
          driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
          jdbc_url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example',
          username='postgres',
          password='postgres',
          statement='INSERT INTO example_table VALUES(?, ?)',
      ))
```

If your data is more complex, it might be easier if you don't define the `NamedTuple` inline, e.g.

```
import typing

class ExampleRow(typing.NamedTuple):
    id: int
    name: unicode
```

and register as in the official example above.